# Rails ActionText to_attachable_partial_path ignored on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I have my models setup like this, making page override the default partial path

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_rich_text :body
end
```

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionText::Attachable
  
  def to_attachable_partial_path
    "pages/page_embed"
  end
```

On creating a new post, the attachment displays the correct partial `pages/page_embed`

[image: New post view]

And again on show `pages/page_embed`

[image: Show post view]

But on edit, it shows `pages#page`

[image: edit post view]

My _form code for that field is

`<%= form.rich_text_area :body, rows: 4, data: { target: "attachments.editor" } %>`

anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionText::Attachable
  
  def to_attachable_partial_path
    "pages/page_embed"
  end

  # this
  def to_trix_content_attachment_partial_path
    to_attachable_partial_path
  end
end
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actiontext/lib/action_text/attachable.rb#L70*

I think, maybe this was overlooked when `to_attachable_partial_path` was [introduced](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40308). The docs say:

> Action Text renders embedded `<action-text-attachment>` elements by resolving their `sgid` attribute into an instance. Once resolved, that instance is passed along to `render`. The resulting HTML is embedded as a descendant of the `<action-text-attachment>` element.

> To render a different partial, define User#to_attachable_partial_path:

Doesn't really say anything about editing. And if you remove the default `users/_user.html.erb` the edit page breaks. I was thinking *ActiveStorage* images render no problem, what do they do: they [ignore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actiontext/lib/action_text/engine.rb#L48) that method. I guess when they say `render` it doesn't include rendering the edit field.